# Python Beautiful Soup and Regex - Double quotes not getting replaced

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape [this website](http://www.sanfoundry.com/operating-system-mcqs-process-scheduling-queue/) using BeautifulSoup and Regex. While doing so, I encountered a question which was having "double quotes" and I wanted to replace the "double quotes" and save it as a .txt file. But it is not replacing the "double quotes". We tried .replace() method but I failed. The code is as follows:

```
url = 'http://www.sanfoundry.com/operating-system-mcqs-process-scheduling-queue/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content)
data = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'entry-content'})
data1 = data[0].text
pattern = r'^\d{1,2}[\.|\)]([\s|\S].*)|(^[a-z]\)\s.*)|^View Answer\s?(Answer:.*)'
#pattern = r'^\d{1,2}[\.|\)]\s*(.*)|(^[a-z]\)\s.*)|^View Answer\s?(Answer:.*)'
reg = re.compile(pattern)
#with open(r'C:\Users\dhvani\Google Drive\Python\Data Scraping\byb.txt', 'a') as f:
with open(r'C:\Users\Jeri_Dabba\Google Drive\Python\Data Scraping\byb.txt', 'a') as f:

    for i in data1.split('\n'):
        if reg.search(i).group(1):
           y = reg.search(i).group(1)
           y = y.replace('"', '')
           f.write(y + "\n")
```

When I checked the .txt file the "double quotes" was not replaced. What might be the problem?

I am new to python.

Comment: If you already have plain text you run the regex against, please post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website includes characters that aren't 'normal' double quote characters i.e. not `"` U+0022

The site includes right and left double quotation marks unicode `“`  `”` U+201C and U+201D

You can replace these:

```
y = y.replace('"', '')
y = y.replace('“', '')
y = y.replace('”', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the website you are trying to scrape.
Is " “Blocked” " an exemple of the double quotes you are trying to replace ? If so, look at the difference between my own quote and the ones that i copy pasted from the website. They are not the same character.

You should copy/paste or find the code of the punctuation characters you are trying to replace, because for one sign, there are a variety of characters used on the web and python will make a difference between " and  “ and  ”.

Hence you should have something like :

```
y = y.replace('“', '');
y = y.replace('”', '');
```

Since this probably won't be your only problem with punctuation marks, i suggest you do an array with everything you want to replace and then loop on that array.