# Extracting a chunk of text between <p> tags

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup

I've got some sample html that I am trying to parse and extract data from. This is what the data looks like:

```
<div class="content">
<h1 class = “heading1”>MOVIE TITLE<h1>
<h2 class="heading2”>Synopsis</h2>
<div>
<p>this text is the synopsis of the movie.</p>
</div>
<h2 class="heading2”>Cast</h2>
<div>
<p>The cast includes</p>
<ol>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<h1 class = “heading1”>MOVIE TITLE<h1>
<h2 class="heading2”>Synopsis</h2>
<div>
<p>this text is the synopsis of the movie.</p>
</div>
<h2 class="heading2”>Cast</h2>
<div>
<p>The cast includes</p>
<ol>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to ideally extract four parts, the title, synopsis and cast list. So far, parsed it and used beautiful soup to extract each movie instance:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = open("movies.txt",'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

I've extracted the each movie like so:

```
movies = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'content'})
```

and the titles from each movie

```
movies.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':'heading1'})
```

Fairly easy since they have unique class attributes.

I would like to also extract the synopsis; just that single line in between the `<p>` tags; and list of cast separately, like I did with the title. However, so far I able to do

```
movies.find_all('h2', attrs={'class':'heading2'})
```

which as you can imagine just gives me "Synopsis" and "Cast"

Comment: Is the html you provided correct? I mean, it seems it is repeated two times. Moreover, look at the second line. The `<h1>` tag is not correctly closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using BeautifulSoup to find a HTML tag that contains certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866000/using-beautifulsoup-to-find-a-html-tag-that-contains-certain-text) .. also: [BeautifulSoup - search by text inside a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958637/beautifulsoup-search-by-text-inside-a-tag) - 
[How to find tag with particular text with Beautiful Soup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007653/how-to-find-tag-with-particular-text-with-beautiful-soup)

Comment: I'm going to rummage around with BeautifulSoup to explore its RE usage. I haven't used it in years. Anywho this will work for the time being. `>>> import re` ,, `>>> re.findall('>Synopsis</[\S]+?>[\S\s]*?<p>([\S\s]*?)</p>', string)`

Comment: The closing quote for `heading2` does not match its *opening* quote. `ord('”') --> 8221;  ord('"') --> 34` You might want to wholesale replace those before doing anything else. ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021721/2823755

Comment: @wwii Whelp, this brought back why I despise BeautifulSoup. To me it makes everything more complicated, behaves wildly differently across the versions, and makes use of regex difficult and inconsistent. I looked at and tried to get results from the posts you mentioned and gagged. Don't know if it's because I'm in Py2.7 but, regardless. BS4 is a headache for me,

Answer (score 1):

This is using Beautiful Soup 4.7+. You should be able to target the `p` element quite easily with CSS selectors.

To get the synopsis we are going to use the level 4 selector feature `:nth-child(an+b of s)`. This will allow us to select the first child that matches the selector `s`, which will be the first `h2.heading2` tag, and then we will use `+ div` to select the next `div` sibling and `> p` to select the direct `p` child.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="content">
<h1 class="heading1">MOVIE TITLE</h1>
<h2 class="heading2">Synopsis</h2>
<div>
<p>this text is the synopsis of the movie.</p>
</div>
<h2 class="heading2">Cast</h2>
<div>
<p>The cast includes</p>
<ol>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<h1 class="heading1">MOVIE TITLE</h1>
<h2 class="heading2">Synopsis</h2>
<div>
<p>this text is the synopsis of the movie.</p>
</div>
<h2 class="heading2">Cast</h2>
<div>
<p>The cast includes</p>
<ol>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
<li>Actor</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for movie in soup.select('div.content'):
    print(movie.select_one('h1.heading1').text)
    print(movie.select_one(':nth-child(1 of h2.heading2) + div > p').text)
    for actor in movie.select('ol > li'):
        print(actor.text)
```

Output:

```
MOVIE TITLE
this text is the synopsis of the movie.
Actor
Actor
Actor
Actor
Actor
MOVIE TITLE
this text is the synopsis of the movie.
Actor
Actor
Actor
Actor
Actor
```

Comment: I did have to fix some typos in the original HTML provided in the opening post.

Comment: what is the _of s_ please?

Comment: It's a new level 4 feature: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo. It kind of behaves like :nth-of-type for any selector. Check out the spec to learn a bit more. But I'll admit the spec can be a little confusing at times.

Comment: I recognise the an+b  having just looked at the guidance as I know it as 1n+1 etc.. but the _of s_ appears to be a selector list. So this could be using, for example, not:(x,y,z) to exclude?  +

Comment: So, as the spec reads now, it does support selector lists, and I do as well. A recent change in the spec is coming to limit it to compound selectors in level 4 and then complex selectors in level 5. We support level 5 right now (level 5 basically means combinator support).

Answer (score 0):

Your content has [Right Double Quotes Marks](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) - replace them first.
Replace errant characters; find the synopsis heading; extract the very next `div`.

```
# s = your html
trans = str.maketrans({8221:34})    
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.translate(trans),"html.parser")
contents = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'content'})
for content in contents:
    syn = content.find('h2', text='Synopsis')
    print(syn, syn.fetchNextSiblings()[0].text)
```